# How to fix Grub2 invalid prefix on startup

Tags: grub2, dual-boot

Some time ago I updated Windows 10 on my dual boot machine (Win10 + Linux).
Since then everytime I start my computer, I'm greeted with

```
  grub rescue>
```

and have to type:

```
set prefix=(hd0,gpt7)/grub
insmod normal
normal
```

to get to GRUB graphical OS picker, where after choosing OS, that OS gets loaded and I'm ready to go.

My question is, how can I make `prefix=(hd0,gpt7)/grub` by deafult.
Currently default is `prefix=(hd0,gpt6)/grub)`

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your configuration and distribution, but updating GRUB should do the trick.

On debian based systems `sudo update-grub`.

Answer (score 0):

Solution was

```
sudo update-grub
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
```

from here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/119597/grub-rescue-error-unknown-filesystem